# Why can I not ask a question here?

Tags: support

I have only 4 questions, now I am getting the message: No questions are accepted from this account. Why?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/225179

Answer (score 6):

Six out of ten questions that you asked were closed as off-topic.

Moreover, in each case the reason for closing was the same

> This question appears to be off-topic because EITHER it is not about
>   statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, or data
>   visualization, OR it focuses on programming, debugging, or performing
>   routine operations within a statistical computing platform. If the
>   latter, you could try the support links we maintain.

In cases where many of the questions by a user are closed, they get *automatically* suspended by the system.

Comment: But those questions are closed.

Comment: You got suspended *because* many of your questions got closed as off-topic.

Comment: I cannot even see these questions anymore and all my other questions are related to machine learning.

Comment: Because closed questions get automatically deleted after some period of time.

Comment: But I am still penalized for those?

Comment: I can understand that people who spam the platform are banned, but I asked 10 questions in like three years??? And now out of the blue I cannot ask questions anymore?

Comment: And why can you see those questions and I don't??

Comment: Well, this platform seemed always a too bit limited in scope and it has been pretty useless.

Comment: I can see those questions, because I'm a moderator. You would be able to see them with more reputation points.

Comment: @Sören, no one takes pleasure in your frustration here. At the same time, disparaging CV won't win any converts to your cause. Thousands of questions here and many people helped by a lot of hard work by many dedicated volunteers and the best you can come up is "pretty useless". I say no more.